# Create mp4 from Google Slides with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am trying to convert Google Slides into an mp4 file and also add audio/mp3 to it.

Currently I am using the method "presentations.pages.getThumbnail" to get the slides in PNG format, which I am sending - UrlFetchApp.fetch() - together with the mp3 file to a VM within GCP. There I have installed [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and the npm package [videoshow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videoshow). The VM sends the final mp4 file back to GAS where it is stored to Google Drive.

The problem is: it is very slow, sometimes the fetch times out. I have found a [Google Workspace Marketplace addon](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/creator_studio/509621243108) which does exactly what I am trying to do but very fast.

Is there a way to create the mp4 file within GAS? Or any other way which is faster than my VM method?

Comment: Its a professional secret for him, I am too interested to know its working. But I am sure he doesn't tell that.

Comment: The addon uses client side lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifshot